# How to do this in Laravel, subquery where not in

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to transform this query in Laravel Format, I try use the 'WhereNotIn' , but I dont' have the result what I want. Somebody can help me?

```
SELECT
em.erp_mlbid AS category_id

FROM
erp_product AS ep
INNER JOIN
erp_product_description AS epd ON epd.erp_productid = ep.erp_productid
INNER JOIN
erp_product_category AS epc ON epc.erp_productid = ep.erp_productid
INNER JOIN
erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory AS emc ON emc.erp_categoryid = epc.erp_categoryid
INNER JOIN
erp_mlb_category AS em ON em.erp_mcid = emc.erp_mlbcategoryid
INNER JOIN
erp_product_image AS epi ON epi.erp_productid = ep.erp_productid
WHERE
ep.erp_productid NOT IN (
SELECT
epm.erp_productid
FROM
erp_product_to_mlb AS epm
)
AND ep.erp_quantity > 0
AND ep.erp_status > 0
LIMIT
                    1
```

Apparently my line 'WhereNotIn' is ignored and the result is the same:

```
 $categoria = DB::table('erp_product')
                            ->join('erp_product_category','erp_product_category.erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product.erp_productid')
                            ->join('erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_categoryid', '=','erp_product_category.erp_categoryid')
                            ->join('erp_mlb_category', 'erp_mlb_category.erp_mcid', '=', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_mlbcategoryid')
                            ->select('erp_mlb_category.erp_mlbid')
                            ->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid', function($q){
                                $q->select('erp_productid')->from('erp_product_to_mlb');
                            })
                            ->get();
```

Comment: could it be you need to do 
`->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_producid', function($q){
                                $q->select('erp_productid')->from('erp_product_to_mlb')->get();
})`

Comment: @FMashiro I tried that, but returns 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::get‌​()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_producid'
```

Should be:

```
->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid'
```

Notice the misspelled `productid`.

---

One thing you can do to debug is to remove the `->get()` call so that `$categoria` is a query object, and then do this so you can see the assembled query:

```
dd($categoria->toSql());
```

Comment: I fix it, but is not that. My whereNotIn still ignored.

Comment: Does the `erp_product_to_mlb` table have any records?

Comment: Yeah, 2 thousand records.

Comment: I just added something for you to try for debugging. See what the actual assembled query ends up being.

Comment: I installed 'Debugbar' for Laravel and returns: 
`select `erp_mlb_category`.`erp_mlbid` from `erp_product` inner join `erp_product_category` on `erp_product_category`.`erp_productid` = `erp_product`.`erp_productid` inner join `erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory` on `erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory`.`erp_categoryid` = `erp_product_category`.`erp_categoryid` inner join `erp_mlb_category` on `erp_mlb_category`.`erp_mcid` = `erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory`.`erp_mlbcategoryid` where `erp_product`.`erp_productid` not in (select `erp_productid` from `erp_product_to_mlb`)`

Comment: The query looks correct from an outside perspective. Have you tried manually running the query in a SQL editor just to see what happens and tweak it to see if you can make it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144467/discussion-between-vinicius-rosa-and-jeremy-harris).